# Could not load Spritefont asset as a non-content file

Tags: c#, monogame, spritefont

I'm switching a game from [xna](/questions/tagged/xna) to [monogame](/questions/tagged/monogame) and hit a snag.

I've got my **.spritefont** file in *project_name*/**Content**, it's listed in the solution explorer, and I'm loading it with this line:

```
debug_font = Content.Load<SpriteFont> ("Kooten");
```

But I'm getting the error:

> *"Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException occurred in Monogame.Framework.dll.
>   Could not load Kooten asset as a non-content file!"*

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For adding a `SpriteFont` in [monogame](/questions/tagged/monogame), you need to create it in a Content project of an  [xna](/questions/tagged/xna) type, compile the game and then copy the generated `xnb` file over to the [monogame](/questions/tagged/monogame) project (the file can be located in the output directory path). Then change its properties so that it is set as "Content" and copied to the output folder if newer.

[image]

You can find the full explanation on [this blog](http://nahuelianni.azurewebsites.net/adding-sound-and-sprite-fonts-on-monogame/).

Comment: Thanks!  I located the original .xnb my former XNA project generated and used that.  It works perfectly now.

Comment: Glad I could be of help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Under solution explorer, click and highlight the file. In the file properties make sure the "Build Action" drop-down has "Content" selected.

Comment: I don't see a field "Type" but I do see "Build Action".  I set this to "Content", but it did not change the result.

Comment: @NightmareGames Sorry, did not have Visual Studio handy when I replied. Fixed. Like the other answer suggests, also make sure it is an .xnb file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to Rebuild solution after making these changes...!